# How can I add five items in UIapplicationShortcutItem?

Tags: swift, uiapplicationshortcutitem

I have tried in AppDelegate:

```
let item1 = UIApplicationShortcutItem(type: "Item", localizedTitle: "Item")
let item2 = UIApplicationShortcutItem(type: "Item", localizedTitle: "Item")
let item3 = UIApplicationShortcutItem(type: "Item", localizedTitle: "Item")
let item4 = UIApplicationShortcutItem(type: "Item", localizedTitle: "Item")
let item5 = UIApplicationShortcutItem(type: "Item", localizedTitle: "Item")

UIApplication.shared.shortcutItems = [item1 , item2 , item3 , item4 , item5]
```

But it shows only 4 of these items. However some apps can make it with five items. As an example Linkedin could add five items in shortcuts. Is it possible to add 5 items to shortcut items?

[image]

Comment: You can only add 4.  If the app is downloaded from the App Store then it automatically gets a "Share AppName" item added to it which would be the 5th one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 10, Apple added a "Share" shortcut item to every app. The bottom four are app-specific, defined by using UIShortcutItem, while the fifth and top one is added by the operating system.

http://www.idownloadblog.com/2016/06/16/ios-10-tidbit-3d-touch-share-apps/

This is a similar post:
[Share App application shortcut [UIApplicationShortcutIconTypeShare]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39440756/share-app-application-shortcut-uiapplicationshortcuticontypeshare)